# Printing Telerik reports using ReportProcessor class

Tags: c#, reporting-services, telerik, reporting

**Firstly let me describe my setup.**

I have a REST Telerik Reporting service. The service operates with TRDX file (have a requirement to have reports in this template format). I also have a console application, which is periodically started by a windows service. This console application uses ReportProcessor class to print reports directly to a printer.

**Now the problem.**

ReportProcessor throws an exception when trying to access the reports using UriReportSource, when these report files are hosted in IIS together with the REST Reporting service. Browsing and Anonymous Authentication are enabled on IIS for the Reports folder. The error that's thrown is:

*The remote server returned an error: (404) not found.*

However reports are printed when TRDX files are located in the same folder as the console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own question by trial and error.

My reports were located in the REST service's subdirectory. So I was trying to set the Uri to the reports URL something like this:

```
UriReportSource reportSource = new UriReportSource { 
    Uri = "http://localhost/myTelerikRESTService/Reports/samplereport.trdx" 
};
```

And I was obviously getting 404 error since the request to the that path would be handled by the service.

Trying to specify a physical path (`c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myTelerikService\Reports\samplereport.trdx`) also ended up in error: something like `the path format is not supported`.

Finally I've tried this Uri: `/inetpub/wwwroot/myTelerikService/Reports/samplereport.trdx`, that maps to the physical location.

And it worked!

**EDIT:**

I really should've read this https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html before working on this issue. Apparently I had no firm understanding of what a URI is! Feeling really dumb now.....